# How to make PopupMenu[x, {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6}] to list its items not only one column?

Tags: wolfram-mathematica, popupmenu

I know `SetterBar[x, {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6}, Appearance -> "Horizontal" -> {2, Automatic}]` will list its items in 2x3 grid style. But how to make `PopupMenu[x, {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6}]` to list its items in 2x3 grid style?

Thanks